# Ubuntu 20.04 Automatic Login Not Working Consistently

Tags: security, 20.04

I installed 20.04 on new hardware and configured Users to use automatic login since the machine will be used by multiple users in the household and will not store valuable data.  Settings -> Users shows that automatic login is enabled and using the account I created.   Most times upon power up the automatic login feature works as expected.  But about 1 in every four boots, the screen goes to the manual login screen.  This seems to occur randomly.  Once it occurs, if I power the machine off and back on, it usually executes an automatic login.  Not sure which package controls this feature so I have not submitted it as a bug.

Comment: Can you manually login or do you have to reboot and manual login doesn't work either as described in https://askubuntu.com/a/1261236/245048?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing worked for me (Ubuntu 20.04) until I did this:

- turned off Autologin on my user
- created a new 'testuser' and set Autologin on that user
- confirmed that Autologin worked for testuser
- removed Autologin from testuser and turned it back on for my user

I guess something was stuck and this unstuck it.

Comment: yeah, that worked for me. crazy. thx!

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: Disable splash from /etc/default/grub (+update-grub)

I found this related workaround for Ubuntu 19.04. It seems related to the splash screen and NVIDIA proprietary driver (and possibly other drivers?). Editing the grub configuration allowed autologin on my system.
Also, recall that Ctrl+Shift+F2 brings up a text console that works even if autologin causes an infinite login loop.

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/01/login-loop-auto-login-enabled-in-ubuntu-19-10-with-nvidia-driver/

Comment: it works on ubuntu 20.04 with Nvidia driver.