# Autologin option in user settings does not persist 22.04

Tags: 22.04, auto-login

Whilst there have been older questions asked, it might be worth putting this in for Jammy 22.04

Settings, User, Unlock , click automatic login.
there are no 'apply buttons'
repeat this, and the option is still disabled.

ASUS AMD Ryzen 5
latest BIOS.

I have also edited the config file for gdm3
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

hashtag  Enabling automatic login

AutomaticLoginEnable = true
AutomaticLogin = user1
[ my username put in there for user1, was that a mistake, should it be 'user1' ]

running from command line I got a funky error message... which had bug history for previous Ubuntu versions. and running
sudo gnome-control-center
got an error message.

this is a new and clean install.

Comment: seeing this solution that worked for someone, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236148/ubuntu-20-04-automatic-login-not-working-consistently I booted into a live and created a new user. the autologin toggle was saved, though logout required the password again, but it was still checked in settings . I also tried that in my 22.04 install, it did not take.

Comment: this is what I get after setting the auto login toggle , running from terminal gnome-control-center "SetAutomaticLogin call failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Accounts.Error.Failed: failed to change automatic login: Key file does not start with a group"

Comment: and looking at the logs...  this...again

SetAutomaticLogin call failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Accounts.Error.Failed: failed to change automatic login: Key file does not start with a group

Answer (score 0):

I had, inadvertently, removed the [daemon ] top part of /etc/gdm/custom.conf

which now is in total.

```
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable = true
AutomaticLogin = [user, me, ]
WaylandEnable=true
```

now automatic login works and the button in settings, user, automatic login holds. seems like [daemon] is the group it was looking for

Comment: on the other hand, autologin works on reboot, but NOT on suspend login screen. why? bounty is still up for that one.

Comment: and automatic login does not work on resume from hibernate

Comment: no need for login on suspend now...  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389431/password-prompt-on-login-only-not-on-lock-screen

Comment: just to bring out the answer for suspend login auto, it is in settings, privacy. not quite where I expected to find it. seems to make the whole suspend process a lot slower too, though I have not tested that much.

Comment: then again it did want the password the last time  I suspened. think I will leave it at that.